# How to refer to a dataframe column using a single character string

Tags: r, function, dataframe, get

I have a dataframe df1 with a column `col1`.

- `df1$col1` returns a vector of the contents of `col1`.
- `df1[["col1"]]` does the same.

How do I store the character string "df1$col1" or "df1[[\"col1\"]]" in a variable, and then use that variable to fetch the same column?

The documentation for `get()` suggests that it does this, but in fact it returns an error: "object 'df1[["col1"]]' not found." So obviously I am missing something.

Any suggestions?

Note: There are lots of questions about storing the name of the column alone in a variable, and then fetching the column from a "hard-coded" data frame thus: `dfcolname <- "col1"; df1[[dfcolname]]`. But that's not what I want to do.

Comment: Don't do that "df1$col1".  Instead create a function if this is to be applied on multiple datasets. `f1 <- function(data, colName){doStuff(data[[colName]])}; f1(df1, "col1")`

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Are you trying to store un-evaluated code and evaluate it later? That can be very messy. Exactly what use case do you have here. There may be much better ways to accomplish what you like.

Comment: If you tell us a little more about the context in which you want to do this we might be able to suggest safer/more efficient alternatives.

Comment: Thank you. I did not find that when I searched.

Comment: To answer the use case question: I have a dataframe dfsummary, which contains summary stats on data stored in other dataframe columns, e.g. df1$col1, df2$col2, etc., one per row. I want a single field at the beginning of each row of dfsummary that points to the relevant dataframe and column for that row. I would like then to be able to write a function that would update one row manually, e.g. updaterow("df1$col1") or somesuch. Happy to entertain a better way of doing that.

Comment: @Bolio You need two fields then, not a single one. The first would hold the name of the data frame the second would hold the column. Say these were named `df` and `col`, then you could do `get(df[1])[col[1]]` say to get the object and then subset it (in this case for the first row in the `dfsummary`). But even that may be sub-optimal given your real use-case, but you'll need to ask a new, different question to try to sort that out.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** do this, but you probably shouldn't.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=1:3)
x <- "df1$col1"
eval(parse(text=x))
```

I'm sure it feels ridiculous to be told "don't do this", but many old-time R users will say from experience that using solutions based on `eval(parse(...))` tends to cause more problems than it solves.

There are a [bunch of questions on StackOverflow discussing why/how to avoid `eval(parse(...))`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+eval+parse+avoid)

Comment: Or maybe slightly better: `x <- quote(df1$col1); eval(x)`

Comment: @MrFlick that works better if you have access to the expression to start with.  Maybe the OP only has the string.

Comment: It seems in most of these cases the next thing they try is `eval(parse(text=x))<-4:6` which is just another headache.

Answer (score 2):

### How do you do this?

One way is to use the `eval(parse())` idiom:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = letters[1:3])
x <- 'df$col1'
y <- 'df[["col2"]]'

> eval(parse(text = x))
[1] 1 2 3
> eval(parse(text = y))
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
```

### Should you do this?

Probably not; as @akrun says, don't do this out of preference just because you can do it.